# Why does a black hole grow when it consumes matter? Isn't this a contradiction?

Tags: black-holes, mass, event-horizon, accretion-disk

I've been thinking about this for a while but can't get my head around it.

A black hole's mass is such that its gravity can overcome light. Its event horizon, as I see it, is the boundary up to which light is "pulled back" into the black hole, from the black hole's point of view.

Surely then, if a black hole consumes more mass, therefore it's gravity would be greater and thus exert a greater force on the light, pulling it tighter, resulting in a smaller black hole...

Judging by the overwhelming amount of information out there suggesting a black hole increases in size, I've obviously got something wrong and would love to be enlightened..

Thx
Mark.

Comment: Read carefully your second and third paragraph. You first say that the horizon is the boundary up to which light is pulled back into the black hole. Then you say the gravitational pull of the black hole increases when you increase its mass. And then you claim this somehow would lead to the boundary up to which light is pulled back *shrinking*, i.e. at a position where the light was formerly trapped it is now free. This just doesn't follow from what you said before.

Comment: Nope. I still don't get it. More mass = greater gravity. Greater gravity = more pull. More pull = smaller...

Comment: The event horizon is not a "thing" that can be pulled in by the black hole...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Surely then, if a black hole consumes more mass, therefore it's gravity would be greater and thus exert a greater force on the light, pulling it tighter, resulting in a smaller black hole...

To use your logic, if the gravity is stronger, then things (and light) farther away that used to not be trapped can now be trapped by the stronger gravity, hence that boundary between where things are trapped and where things aren't trapped is now farther out, and that's the size of the black hole, so the size is larger.

There is a still a potential hole in your argument however. Which is that you just assumed the black hole could consume things. But if something happens it is reasonable to ask when and where it happened, which is a hard thing to answer for a black hole.

People on the outside never see a black hole form and they never see a black hole consume something. They see stuff that starts to look more and more like a black bole as time goes on. And they see new stuff join up and the new larger collection start to look more and more like a black hole.

This is basically because of extreme time dilation between the forming surface and the outside where we see the things near the forming surface going slowly.

And if it is an astrophysical black hole, there isn't even a surface we just see the original matter say the neutron star collapsing in slower and slower slow motion and getting redder and redder.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds like it but I wasn't presenting an argument more of a "WTF!" :)

Comment: @ScaryAardvark Sure, but if you say "what if something that never happens actually happened" and then got a contradiction you shouldn't actually be surprised. In your case you were just wrong about it getting smaller, but since you started by assuming something happened that doesn't happen then it wouldn't have been a problem even if there were an actual contradiction.

Comment: I realise that my supposition was wrong based on the overwhelming evidence against it. I just couldn't understand in my mind why it was the way it was...

Comment: @ScaryAardvark I still don't know if you understand my answer. The point is that you never ever ever see black holes consume things, but even if you broke the laws of physics and forced it to do so. It would still get bigger, for exactly the reason I mention in my answer the greater pull makes the transition from inside (within that pull) to outside (beyond that pull) happen farther out.

Comment: You haven't answered the question though. Why does it happen farther out and not closer in.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark I literally did. The stronger gravity means things farther away now get pulled in as hard as things closer in used to be pulled in. So the cut off is now farther out. Which is a moot point since that isn't what happens.

Comment: Ah. Ok, I think I understand a little better now. So the black hole is getting bigger because it has more "reach" with it having more gravity due to the extra mass?

Comment: @ScaryAardvark Pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely then, if a black hole consumes more mass, therefore it's gravity would be greater and thus exert a greater force on the light, pulling it tighter, resulting in a smaller black hole...

Define size of a black hole:

The [Schwarzschild radius](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/blkhol.html#c2) :

> The Schwarzschild radius (event horizon) just marks the radius of a sphere past which we can get no particles, no light, no information.

[image: Schwarzradius]

Note that the radius, which defines the volume from which there is no return, is proportional to the mass, so the larger the mass the larger the volume of the black hole trap.

Your misunderstanding comes from "pulling it tighter". The strength of the gravitational field of the larger in mass black hole extends further then when it was  smaller in mass.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the blackhole (i.e. its blackness) is not its actual size. It is the area where light simply cannot escape. The more mass the blackhole gets, the wider this area be due to increased gravity pull. It's actual size? We do not know but it is assumed as a singularity at its center.

Answer (score 0):

The [density of a black hole](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/physics/86-the-universe/black-holes-and-quasars/general-questions/423-what-is-the-density-of-a-black-hole-advanced) is concentrated at the singularity at its center, where density becomes infinite and the Theory of Relativity breaks down.  Although the Theory of Relativity is insufficient to describe what happens at the singularity, it may be assumed that the density at that point can not increase.  Therefore, accretion of matter does not increase the density at the singularity, but rather increases the Schwarzschild radius of the black hole, expanding the event horizon.  Gravity increases, but so does the size of the black hole.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to realise is that the event horizon is not a boundary that light rays can rise up to before being drawn down again. Light rays inside a black hole never travel upwards towards the event horizon. When they enter the blackhole light rays travel inevitably to the central singularity. If an infalling observer falls through the event horizon and they have a lamp that shines in 'all directions' no light rays from that lamp will ever reach a higher altitude than the altitude they were emitted from. There is no residual ball of trapped light rays inside the event horizon that can be drawn into a tighter sphere.